# Custom Desktop Launchers not sticking after restart in Unity 2D panel

Tags: 11.04, unity, unity-2d

I have a handful of customer launchers that I'd like to place in the Unity 2D launcher. I have created them as desktop configuration files, and stored them in a shortcuts folder. When I click on these from Nautilus, they work fine. If I drag them to the Unity launcher, they work properly. If I reboot, they don't stay in the panel. How do I get them to be remembered?

Answer (score 1):

Desktop configuration files are not necessary for Unity or Unity 2D.
Just launch programs you like in the launcher. Then right click on their icon in the launcher and mark "Keep on launcher".